# Using EWS to update calendar name in Outlook.com doesn't register online

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook.com

I'm using Exchange Web Services to update a calendar name by setting the DisplayName property and then calling .Update().

It works in the sense that the call completes, and retrieving the calendar through EWS later, the DisplayName *has* changed, but Outlook.com doesn't register it and just shows the old name.

So basically it works but Outlook.com ignores it. I'm following the code sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633615(v%3dexchg.80)

```
Folder folder = Folder.Bind(service, folderId);
folder.DisplayName = "Updated folder name";
folder.Update();
```

Comment: Do you see the change in Windows Outlook? Are you updating the default Calendar folder or one of the custom folders?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I don't have Microsoft Outlook the client, but in the Windows 10 calendar app the name has also not changed (also it seems you cannot change the name of calendars or even add new ones in that app?). I'm updating a custom folder (calendar) I created online.